# Declare an enum with Android context class in static field warning

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

I wish to add an enum to my activity.
This enum will contain an EditText class.

I'm getting this warning on my enum:

```
Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to Day which has field editText pointing to EditText); this is a memory leak
```

Here is my code:

```
enum class Day(val num: Int, var editText: EditText?, val rStringInt: Int) {
    mon(2, null, R.string.lmon),
    tue(3, null, R.string.ltue),
    wed(4, null, R.string.lwed),
    thurs(5, null, R.string.lthurs),
    fri(6, null, R.string.lfri),
    sat(7, null, R.string.lsat),
    sun(1, null, R.string.lsun)
}
```

In my activity, I have an onCreate method which assigns each Day's editText value manually. I couldn't seem to get a one-liner kinda thing going here:

```
Day.mon.editText = mon
Day.tue.editText = tue
Day.wed.editText = wed
Day.thurs.editText = thurs
Day.fri.editText = fri
Day.sat.editText = sat
Day.sun.editText = sun
```

How can I make it so that I don't receive this error on my Day enum? I've tried putting the enum in my Activity class, but it still gives me an warning.

Edit: Sorry, it's a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be passing views to enums fields which are static by default.  Views are bound to the lifecycle of Activities and static fields last the lifetime of the entire application process. So assigning a view to an enum field prevents the related Activity from being garbage collected when that Activity is no longer in use.  That's the meaning of the warning.

If you just want an easy way to access your views, then just wrap them with a view binder.   This will generate a binding class based on your XML layout.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#0

With the above you can easily access your views from the automatically generated binding class such as the example in the code lab.

```
val binding : PlainActivityBinding =
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.plain_activity)

binding.name = "Your name"
binding.lastName = "Your last name"
```

Comment: Still, this didn't solve the question of putting the view in the enum. Since enums are static, how about if I made nested classes? Would those be disposed by the garbage collector if I held a view inside the nested class?

Comment: Or just another class outside of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Still, that would cause a memory leak when your fragment gets recreated.
20 setonclicklisteners? count me in
I did find one other method with resources, though.

Edit: This data should be held in the fragment, since it requires reference to a view. Therefore, the view data shouldn't be held in another class or "enum".
However, the other class is still a good option for holding static variables that wouldn't change (like a reference from integer to string).
When the view gets recreated, it would require you to convert any changes that were made.. complicating your code even further. doing so seems impractical for the few lines you've "saved". <s>One alternative is not editing the previous data, and just not using the previous views that were encapsulated, still enabling you to save the few lines for setting on click listeners.</s>

I have resorted to the following solution:

Create a seperate Days class with a nested Day class, which looks like the following:

```
class Days {
    val mon: Day = Day(2, null)
    val tue: Day = Day(3, null)
    val wed: Day = Day(4, null)
    val thurs: Day = Day(5, null)
    val fri: Day = Day(6, null)
    val sat: Day = Day(7, null)
    val sun: Day = Day(1, null)

    data class Day(val num:Int, var editText: EditText?)
}
```

Then, in my activity, I instantiate it:

```
private val days: Days = Days()
```

Then reference it like so:

```
days.mon.editText = mon
days.tue.editText = tue
days.wed.editText = wed
days.thurs.editText = thurs
days.fri.editText = fri
days.sat.editText = sat
days.sun.editText = sun
```

This way, since it is not static like an enum, it gets garbage collected along with the activity.

In case you were wondering, the context of this question was established in order to iterate through the enum (now object). This is achievable through this inside of my Days object:

```
val days: Array<Day> = arrayOf(mon, tue, wed, thurs, fri, sat, sun)
```